# Problem after removing Apache2

Tags: apache2, localhost

I've tried to remove Apache2 by :

```
sudo apt-get remove apache2
```

Next :

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

After that, on `http://localhost` still appears following text :

```
It works!

This is the default web page for this server.

The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.
```

Why after removing Apache2 above text still appears?

Comment: have you cleaned the browser cache?

Comment: Also, just to make sure there aren't any apache processes left behind, be sure to restart. FYI, a quick way around the cache is either F5 or Ctrl+F5.

Comment: What's the output of `netstat -tlnp | grep 80`?

Comment: @vfbsilva Your right. I cleared browser cache and fixed.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's probably still running; try `ps aux | grep -E 'httpd|apache'`; if there is a process then it's because you did not stop it.

If it's not running see what is bound to that port by doing `lsof -Pni :80`.